# Flexslider infinite loop is not working

Tags: jquery, infinite-loop, flexslider

I was looking all over the web
there is a very known issue with Flexslider either with the slider or the carousel when it gets to the last item in the slider it flys back to the first one instead of keeping the infinite loop smoothly
I can't believe no one has a solution for that
this is the flexSlider code I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#carousel-two').flexslider({
            animation : "slide",
            controlNav : false,
            animationLoop : true,
            slideshow : true,
            itemWidth : 234,
            itemMargin : 20,
            minItems : 3,
            maxItems : 5
            //asNavFor : '.flexslider'
        });
    });
});
```

No matter what I do it doesn't work. when it gets to the last item it doesn't keep the animation smoothly with infinite loop.
does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I think the carousel will not loop infinitely by default. I also encountered this problem. I end up switching to bxslider. :( But have you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately not.. funny thing is I switched to Bxslider too :) just because of that.  it is very wierd flexSlder people don't do nothing to fix it..

Comment: Yeah. I just read here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/287 that the circular loop that we are looking is not yet implemented in flexslider. Too bad, it's not the best responsive slider as woothemes claimed. Haha!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how to do it while keeping the `itemWidth` property:

```
jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        minItems: 4,
        maxItems: 6,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin:5,
        controlNav: false,
        end : function(slider){
                jQuery('.flexslider .slides li').each(function(){
                    slider.addSlide('<li>'+jQuery(this).context.innerHTML+'</li>', slider.count);
                    jQuery('.flexslider .slides').append('<li>'+jQuery(this).context.innerHTML+'</li>');
                });
            }

      });
```

The main thing is to use the jQuery function in the `end:` property. I think `animationLoop` also needs to be set to `false`. This allows for an infinite loop carousel. [Here](http://www.stylo-arts.com/blog/flexslider-infinite-carousel/) is where I found this.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you J

Comment: not working for me...
`mytry.html:221 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous> (mytry.html:221)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:362)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.2.1.js:157)
    at Object.end (mytry.html:220)
    at jQuery.fn.init.slider.flexAnimate (jquery.flexslider.js:730)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (jquery.flexslider.js:326)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)`

Answer (score 2):

if you remove string

```
itemWidth: 234,
```

animationLoop will be work

Answer (score 0):

At least one thing set wrong is you have

```
animationLoop: false,
```

it should be:

```
animationLoop: true,
```

Comment: @Adrian Forsius - even with the animationLoop: true; it is not working and not looping. when it gets to the last item and brings you back to the first one by sliding everything backwards.

Comment: Then one would need a link or a jsfiddle to help you