# Flexslider Carousel Infinite Loop Bug

Tags: jquery

I have 2 flexsliders in my page. One is looping infinitely, while the other one is not. It's weird that the other one is not, while the other one is functioning properly.

Even if I already added animationLoop true to the other slider, it still doesn't loop infinitely. Here's the page where I have 2 flexsliders.

http://robinsons.jehzlau.net/

The one above is looping infinitely, but the one below, is not. I'm really curious why it doesn't loop infinitely.

Here's the code for the above slider. This is the one that loops infinitely:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $jq(window).load(function(){
              $jq('.ma-banner7-container .flexslider').flexslider({
                slideshow: true,
                animation: "slide",
                slideshowSpeed: 5000,
                animationSpeed: 600,
                                controlNav: false,
                                                start: function(slider){
                    $jq('.ma-loading').css("display","none");
                    //$jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des, .banner7-readmore').css("left","100px");
                },
                before: function(){ 
                    $jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des').css("left","-550px");
                    $jq('.banner7-readmore').css("left","-1500px"); 
                }, 
                after: function(){ 
                    $jq('.banner7-title, .banner7-des, .banner7-readmore').css("left","100px") 
                }
              });
            });
        </script>
```

And here's the code for the slider that I want to loop infinitely, but it doesn't. :(

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
            $jq(window).load(function(){
              $jq('.signSlider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                animationLoop: true,
                controlNav: false,
                itemWidth: 270,
                itemMargin: 5,
                slideshow: false
              });
            });
// ]]></script>
```

What I noticed is that the flexslider that loops infintitely doesn't have animationloop: true. So I removed the animation loop in my code for the second slider, but still, it doesn't loop infinitely. :(

Actually it's similar to this already posted question:
[Flexslider infinite loop is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912634/flexslider-infinite-loop-is-not-working)

Any help from a jquery expert would be greatly appreciate. O_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found the question to my answer here:
https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/287

The infinite circular loop is not yet implemented in Flexslider. Too bad, it's not the best responsive slider after all. :(